# jquery autocomplete not coming under the input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery autocomplete here but the list is not coming under the input field but somewhere else i have attached the image! how to fix this ?

[image]

CSS :

```
.ui-autocomplete {
 max-height: 100px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
 overflow-x: hidden;
 /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
 padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Jquery :

```
$('#commandTypeInput').autocomplete({
        source: ["aaa","BBB","ccc","cccd"
                ],
        minLength: 0
    }).focus(function(){
        $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Add fiddle link else try adding position css to the auto-complete element.

Comment: could u please create a working fiddle

Comment: Have you included the CSS file into the page? Besides the part you wrote in the question

Comment: i will create the fiddle and upload asap.

Comment: Better than the screenshot paste the html, I'm almost sure it's a CSS/HTML layout problem. It would be even better if you could provide a fiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yeah its Css/Html problem because i have used position absolute at alot of places to place buttons and divs !